# Webpack not compiling ES2015 script

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack

I am having trouble getting Webpack to compile my ES2015 scripts. It will bundle all the Javascript and SASS files but there no conversion of ES6 to ES5. This is leaving "fat arrows", "let" statements, and other ES6 features in my compiled code.

Please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my webpack.config.js file. It is at the project root. The project files are in /app.v2 with entry.js being at /app.v2/entry.js

```js
module.exports = {
    entry: "entry.js",
    output: {
        path: "app.v2",
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    resolve: {
        modulesDirectories: [
            './app.v2/components',
            './app.v2',
            'node_modules',
            './app.v2/bower_components',
            './app.v2/assets/js'
        ],
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.es6']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.es6$/,
                include: ['./app.v2/components', './app.v2'],
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader?cacheDirectory=cache/babelCache',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015-without-strict']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&minetype=application/font-woff&name=assets/fonts/[name].[ext]"
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: "file-loader?name=assets/fonts/[name].[ext]"
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `babel-loader` will only work on files with extension `.es6`. 
Since your entry point file is `entry.js` this loader is not used.

Change your file extensions to `.es6` or loader test in `webpack.config`

```
{
    test:/\.(js|es6)$/,                            // <-- this line
    include: ['./app.v2/components', './app.v2'],
    exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
    loader: 'babel-loader?cacheDirectory=cache/babelCache',
    query: {
        presets: ['es2015-without-strict']
    }
}
```

Comment: This didn't work. It's still not compiling the ES6 features to ES5.

Comment: try this `entry: "entry.js"` convert to `entry: "./app.v2/entry.js"`

Comment: No love. Same problem.

Comment: last try: change `es2015-without-strict` to `es2015`

Comment: No change. Thanks for trying. This thing has me stumped.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the problem. I removed the include property for the Babel loader and now the files are compiling correctly.

If anyone can explain why this fixed the issue, I would love to learn the reason.

```js
module.exports = {
entry: "entry.js",
output: {
    path: "app.v2",
    filename: "bundle.js"
},
resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: [
        './app.v2/components',
        './app.v2',
        'node_modules',
        './app.v2/bower_components',
        './app.v2/assets/js'
    ],
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.es6']
},
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.(js|es6)$/,
            // include: ['./app.v2/components', './app.v2'], <-- Remove this.
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            loader: 'babel',
            query: {
                cacheDirectory: 'cache/babelCache', // <-- Move all query params to here.
                presets: ['es2015-without-strict']
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]
        },
        {
            test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
            loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&minetype=application/font-woff&name=assets/fonts/[name].[ext]"
        },
        {
            test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
            loader: "file-loader?name=assets/fonts/[name].[ext]"
        }
    ]
}
};
```